# Using new computer with Windows 8. How to import pics?

Tags: windows-8, sync, android

How can one import pics from Android phone to computer using Windows 8?

Comment: [Good luck](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77004/move-photos-from-android-to-pc-wirelessly-in-one-step). The easiest I've seen so far is [Photo Transfer App](http://www.phototransferapp.com/) and [AirDroid](http://www.airdroid.com/). If you *delete* photos off the phone don't forget to delete the thumbnails folder too...

Answer (score 4):

Its an MTP device so... plug it in, open "This PC" in explorer, right click on the device icon that's there (its a mp3 player icon with the model number of your phone for some inconceivable reason) , and select "Import pictures and video". With minor changes this would work with older versions (its "My Computer" on those).

[image]

You can also selectively copy pictures over by doubleclicking on the icon.

There's also phone specific utilities that act let you do this, but this varies with phone.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of problems connecting Galaxy S3 to Windows 8 -- it turns out that the problem seems to be with Android drivers having problems with the machines I am connecting to, all of them are 64-bit if that is the problem. What I have found is to install the airdroid app and the phone pics, music, etc.. are accessible from the computer via web.airdroid.com. It has been a lifesaver.